# Calculating Variance Inflation Factors (VIFs) based on object type in R

Tags: r, regression, r-car

There seem to be two popular ways of calculating VIFs (Variance Inflation Factors, to detect collinearity among variables in regression) in R:

1. The `vif()` function in the `car` package, where the input is the **model**. This requires you to first fit a model before you can check for VIFs among variables in the model.
2. The `corvif()` function, where the input are the actual candidate explanatory variables (i.e. a list of variables, before the model is even fitted). This function is part of the `AED` package (Zuur et al. 2009), which has been discontinued. This one seems to work only on a list of variables, not on a fitted regression model.

Here is a data example:

```
MyData<-structure(list(site = structure(c(3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 1L), .Label = c("R1a", "R1b", "R2", "Za", "Zb"), class = "factor"), 
    species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Monogyna", 
    "Other", "Prunus", "Rosa"), class = "factor"), aspect = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L), .Label = c("East", "Flat", "North", "South", "West"
    ), class = "factor"), height = c(515L, 60L, 60L, 30L, 70L, 
    70L, 40L, 70L, 50L, 75L, 160L, 85L, 40L, 90L, 70L, 210L, 
    30L, 60L, 45L, 60L, 410L, 50L, 40L, 210L, 140L, 120L, 70L, 
    35L, 30L, 90L, 40L, 240L, 40L, 55L, 120L, 200L, 65L, 40L, 
    95L, 140L, 220L, 70L, 40L, 30L, 50L, 95L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    70L, 160L, 45L, 35L, 50L, 70L, 230L, 110L, 300L, 50L, 105L, 
    60L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 30L, 60L, 30L, 110L, 80L, 80L, 30L, 60L, 
    70L, 80L, 60L, 40L, 220L, 140L, 110L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 90L, 
    125L, 90L, 100L, 270L, 420L, 60L, 70L, 53L, 40L, 80L, 90L, 
    30L, 40L, 65L, 40L, 110L, 90L, 40L, 190L, 110L, 70L, 52L, 
    120L, 95L, 50L, 50L, 140L, 75L, 30L, 50L, 60L, 125L, 60L, 
    80L, 35L, 55L, 140L, 140L, 240L, 65L, 40L, 200L, 80L, 60L, 
    65L, 120L, 80L, 230L, 150L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 210L, 50L, 130L, 
    140L, 210L, 60L, 50L, 90L, 120L, 55L, 50L, 20L, 50L, 40L, 
    70L, 40L, 100L, 80L, 85L, 60L, 50L, 20L, 200L, 40L, 70L, 
    50L, 200L, 60L, 43L, 30L, 60L, 40L, 70L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 
    110L, 70L, 30L, 50L, 85L, 70L, 40L, 100L, 40L, 50L, 100L, 
    40L, 70L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 210L, 50L, 140L, 80L, 75L, 90L, 
    40L, 50L, 60L, 50L, 80L, 50L, 60L, 40L, 60L, 170L, 60L, 80L, 
    80L, 15L, 40L, 70L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 110L, 200L, 30L, 60L, 
    40L, 60L, 160L, 40L, 90L, 80L, 30L, 40L, 270L, 50L, 50L, 
    60L, 60L, 50L, 30L, 70L, 170L, 50L, 30L, 50L, 60L, 40L, 60L, 
    60L, 140L, 80L, 80L, 220L, 45L, 80L, 130L, 50L, 40L, 220L, 
    40L, 70L, 60L, 80L, 50L, 200L, 115L, 50L, 90L, 400L, 50L, 
    360L, 40L, 60L, 60L, 65L, 100L, 50L, 55L, 60L, 50L, 130L, 
    40L, 130L, 40L, 40L, 120L, 66L, 55L, 100L, 75L, 60L, 80L, 
    60L, 90L, 160L, 50L, 210L, 35L, 60L, 40L, 55L, 50L, 90L, 
    220L, 60L, 120L, 62L, 60L, 40L, 60L, 70L, 60L, 90L, 50L, 
    50L, 30L, 110L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 210L, 70L, 65L, 160L, 100L, 
    25L, 55L, 40L, 60L, 110L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 60L, 60L, 170L, 
    45L, 60L, 120L, 40L, 60L, 130L, 40L, 170L, 50L, 80L, 60L, 
    150L, 90L, 60L, 120L, 120L, 80L, 30L, 110L, 230L, 190L, 70L, 
    110L, 50L, 60L, 82L, 60L, 30L, 60L, 200L, 90L, 30L, 140L, 
    60L, 70L, 70L, 100L, 60L, 415L, 115L, 90L, 60L, 60L, 80L, 
    60L, 55L, 90L, 65L, 60L, 40L, 40L, 90L, 50L, 70L, 70L, 120L, 
    40L, 50L, 110L, 45L, 30L, 95L, 30L, 70L), width = c(310L, 
    50L, 40L, 30L, 60L, 70L, 20L, 80L, 70L, 20L, 220L, 40L, 60L, 
    30L, 230L, 110L, 20L, 40L, 25L, 60L, 240L, 90L, 30L, 130L, 
    120L, 110L, 60L, 70L, 30L, 110L, 30L, 180L, 20L, 80L, 110L, 
    310L, 40L, 10L, 80L, 160L, 134L, 30L, 20L, 40L, 20L, 230L, 
    100L, 180L, 40L, 120L, 130L, 30L, 40L, 100L, 30L, 180L, 70L, 
    110L, 170L, 40L, 30L, 50L, 30L, 40L, 30L, 50L, 80L, 50L, 
    80L, 90L, 70L, 70L, 190L, 60L, 50L, 30L, 150L, 150L, 50L, 
    80L, 30L, 40L, 130L, 390L, 60L, 130L, 400L, 200L, 110L, 30L, 
    15L, 300L, 70L, 140L, 30L, 50L, 30L, 40L, 110L, 240L, 50L, 
    90L, 70L, 20L, 40L, 100L, 50L, 30L, 30L, 130L, 40L, 70L, 
    70L, 60L, 10L, 30L, 60L, 50L, 40L, 120L, 90L, 210L, 50L, 
    20L, 100L, 100L, 110L, 100L, 100L, 80L, 120L, 80L, 5L, 40L, 
    50L, 60L, 15L, 100L, 120L, 200L, 30L, 80L, 60L, 70L, 30L, 
    30L, 20L, 50L, 50L, 60L, 15L, 80L, 60L, 130L, 40L, 60L, 30L, 
    100L, 20L, 130L, 60L, 120L, 70L, 20L, 60L, 20L, 40L, 50L, 
    15L, 120L, 60L, 50L, 300L, 40L, 30L, 25L, 70L, 130L, 30L, 
    50L, 60L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 20L, 30L, 70L, 35L, 180L, 40L, 50L, 
    70L, 40L, 70L, 50L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 20L, 30L, 
    180L, 30L, 130L, 30L, 15L, 25L, 50L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 
    170L, 20L, 50L, 20L, 50L, 110L, 30L, 90L, 15L, 50L, 40L, 
    150L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 20L, 40L, 20L, 100L, 60L, 40L, 30L, 
    30L, 140L, 40L, 50L, 120L, 150L, 100L, 70L, 300L, 30L, 60L, 
    120L, 30L, 50L, 100L, 60L, 90L, 50L, 40L, 140L, 130L, 60L, 
    60L, 70L, 200L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 80L, 35L, 70L, 
    15L, 40L, 360L, 70L, 50L, 50L, 30L, 110L, 30L, 30L, 90L, 
    50L, 30L, 70L, 40L, 110L, 70L, 40L, 150L, 100L, 40L, 40L, 
    40L, 20L, 250L, 180L, 40L, 60L, 20L, 120L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 
    260L, 110L, 30L, 30L, 40L, 100L, 50L, 50L, 100L, 150L, 190L, 
    70L, 110L, 50L, 10L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 80L, 30L, 20L, 150L, 
    70L, 25L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 30L, 50L, 210L, 40L, 100L, 30L, 
    80L, 20L, 30L, 70L, 130L, 60L, 50L, 50L, 70L, 50L, 30L, 150L, 
    130L, 110L, 50L, 40L, 80L, 90L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 200L, 
    140L, 40L, 25L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 20L, 40L, 340L, 70L, 60L, 
    50L, 20L, 80L, 60L, 25L, 260L, 20L, 15L, 40L, 30L, 300L, 
    120L, 60L, 100L, 50L, 40L, 20L, 90L, 50L, 40L, 80L, 30L, 
    40L), length = c(450L, 80L, 55L, 50L, 90L, 90L, 30L, 90L, 
    90L, 30L, 240L, 50L, 70L, 40L, 380L, 200L, 40L, 40L, 35L, 
    110L, 250L, 120L, 70L, 150L, 130L, 140L, 90L, 90L, 40L, 390L, 
    40L, 190L, 40L, 110L, 140L, 360L, 50L, 30L, 130L, 500L, 200L, 
    30L, 25L, 60L, 30L, 350L, 110L, 180L, 70L, 180L, 200L, 40L, 
    70L, 110L, 70L, 180L, 90L, 150L, 400L, 100L, 60L, 70L, 70L, 
    60L, 30L, 50L, 80L, 180L, 110L, 100L, 110L, 110L, 210L, 80L, 
    70L, 40L, 500L, 210L, 50L, 80L, 40L, 50L, 350L, 400L, 150L, 
    200L, 400L, 280L, 240L, 40L, 50L, 360L, 140L, 140L, 50L, 
    50L, 40L, 50L, 210L, 370L, 70L, 110L, 80L, 50L, 50L, 100L, 
    80L, 50L, 35L, 140L, 60L, 90L, 110L, 60L, 130L, 180L, 70L, 
    70L, 40L, 230L, 130L, 290L, 90L, 40L, 100L, 100L, 120L, 150L, 
    110L, 80L, 220L, 90L, 5L, 50L, 50L, 60L, 30L, 150L, 120L, 
    200L, 60L, 170L, 80L, 90L, 40L, 50L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 100L, 
    15L, 90L, 70L, 150L, 60L, 90L, 50L, 120L, 20L, 220L, 80L, 
    140L, 120L, 30L, 60L, 40L, 40L, 70L, 30L, 180L, 60L, 110L, 
    300L, 50L, 60L, 50L, 110L, 160L, 40L, 70L, 70L, 60L, 70L, 
    50L, 25L, 30L, 215L, 70L, 220L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 60L, 130L, 
    60L, 20L, 60L, 50L, 40L, 60L, 100L, 40L, 70L, 210L, 40L, 
    500L, 40L, 30L, 50L, 80L, 40L, 60L, 80L, 50L, 220L, 20L, 
    70L, 50L, 50L, 180L, 50L, 90L, 15L, 120L, 80L, 170L, 30L, 
    30L, 60L, 20L, 60L, 30L, 140L, 80L, 40L, 50L, 40L, 200L, 
    80L, 80L, 120L, 160L, 210L, 120L, 400L, 60L, 60L, 180L, 70L, 
    70L, 150L, 70L, 110L, 70L, 80L, 250L, 140L, 90L, 60L, 180L, 
    400L, 60L, 50L, 60L, 40L, 30L, 50L, 100L, 40L, 110L, 30L, 
    80L, 400L, 70L, 50L, 80L, 30L, 180L, 70L, 60L, 100L, 70L, 
    50L, 100L, 60L, 220L, 70L, 70L, 200L, 110L, 50L, 110L, 50L, 
    60L, 250L, 220L, 60L, 80L, 35L, 210L, 70L, 70L, 110L, 320L, 
    280L, 60L, 50L, 60L, 100L, 70L, 70L, 170L, 170L, 230L, 80L, 
    130L, 90L, 10L, 60L, 70L, 60L, 120L, 40L, 50L, 160L, 100L, 
    30L, 40L, 40L, 90L, 30L, 80L, 240L, 100L, 170L, 60L, 120L, 
    20L, 40L, 70L, 150L, 80L, 50L, 90L, 130L, 70L, 60L, 480L, 
    150L, 130L, 90L, 70L, 150L, 100L, 70L, 50L, 40L, 60L, 400L, 
    200L, 80L, 30L, 120L, 70L, 50L, 40L, 40L, 360L, 90L, 70L, 
    60L, 40L, 110L, 80L, 25L, 270L, 40L, 25L, 50L, 30L, 320L, 
    150L, 100L, 100L, 60L, 40L, 50L, 100L, 50L, 50L, 200L, 30L, 
    80L), ground = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Grass", 
    "GrassRock", "Rock"), class = "factor"), sun = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L), .Label = c("Half", "Shade", "Sun"), class = "factor"), 
    leaf = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Large", "Medium", 
    "Scarce", "Small"), class = "factor"), Presence = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L)), .Names = c("site", "species", "aspect", "height", "width", 
"length", "ground", "sun", "leaf", "Presence"), row.names = c(NA, 
393L), class = "data.frame")
```

After the model selection, this is the optimal model:

```
model <- glm(Presence ~ site + species + aspect + length + sun 
            + leaf, data=MyData, family=binomial)
```

With respect to the 1st way referred to above, one can do the following:

```
library(car)
vif(model)
```

to obtain VIFs based on the model as an input.

But with respect to 2nd way, one could look at VIFs of variables, before fitting the model:

```
library(AED) # note that his package has been discontinued
vars <- cbind(MyData$site, MyData$species,
MyData$aspect , MyData$length ,
MyData$width, MyData$height,
MyData$ground, MyData$sun, MyData$leaf)
corvif(vars)
```

(the `corvif()` function code can be found here: http://www.highstat.com/Book2/HighstatLibV6.R)

The underlying mathematics of the two functions appear to be the same, but the way the functions are written, they accept different types of objects as input.

My questions are:

1. Do you prefer to calculate VIFs based

   1. on a list of variables prior to model fitting,
   2. on a fitted model, or
   3. both?
2. Are there any functions (in additions to the two referred to already) that people recommend and/or use to calculate VIFs?
3. Is anyone aware of a single R function that works on both the list of variables *and* the fitted model as in input?

Comment: Questions like this (requests for package names) are considered off-topic. (This question also suggests no effort at searching.) It's also unclear what you mean by "actual covariates". How would there be non-actual covariates?

Comment: @42-, apologies, I was not aware this was off-topic. I thought it is exactly this community where such question would be best asked. Regarding effort, I realise I may have missed something, but on the contrary, I have put effort into this. For example, I first tried to better understand the difference of the two functions using [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262087/variance-inflation-factors-vifs-on-model-vs-covariates-themselves?noredirect=1#comment501712_262087). Since I got a better grasp on the differences, I went on to learn if better alternatives exist.

Comment: @42- With "actual covariates" I mean "not inside a fitted model", but rather a list. Sorry, I thought that was implicit from the question, and I tried my best to make that distinction clear. Do you suggest I edit the question, or delete it completely? Thanks.

Comment: The way to rescue questions that have been closed is to post data and code, then request reopening. Then you can ask specific questions with reference to actual data objects. Try to avoid using pronouns by referring to items by "actual" names.

Comment: @42-, with respect to the first point, many thanks, I will consider how I can improve this post. But I respectfully disagree with your second point and do not understand it. "Actual" is not a pronoun, rather an adjective, and I see no reason why I should not use it. I clearly stated "..where the input are the actual candidate explanatory variables (i.e. a list of variables, before the model is even fitted)..", making it clear what I mean. I then merely repeated this in the final question.

Comment: I have now edited the question, making it more clear and specific, and I included data and code. Hopefully this improves it, and makes it more useful to other users as well.

Comment: Dear @Sotos: I have edited the question a few days ago and wondered whether it seems more appropriate now. If so, can it be reopened (put off-hold)? I looked in the help center if there are other ways I should request reopening, but it seems editing and posting a comment is the way to go. Or should I delete the question completely?

Comment: Nominated for reopening. Not sure who can throw the switch, since it was closed with only two votes, suggesting to me that one of those two was a moderator or someone with "special powers".

Comment: Many thanks for reopening!

Answer (score 0):

My (opinionated) answer to the question: whether it's more appropriate to use vif on a model object or on the data itself, would be that it would be best practice to do it before the model is constructed as part of the process of understanding the relationships within the data before modeling. But truth be told, I think most of the time it's done as an afterthought because of unexpected results (standard errors that blow up, usually).

If you want a function that can take either a fit object or a dimensioned data-object (matrix or dataframe), then I think you may need to "roll your own". I have used the rms/Hmisc pair of packages extensively and there is also a `vif` in the 'rms'-package as well as a `which.influence` function that lets you know the combinations that are responsible for the multicollinearity. It only accepts a fit-object. Because the versions that handle fit-objects can look at both the result of `vcov` and the terms in the RHS of the formula, you would only need to have single argument. However, if you want to specify which columns to examine in a dimensioned object, then you would need to provide function code to handle a second parameter.

I did a search with:

```
 sos::findFn("vif")
```

... and the fourth page examined (function `vif` in package "HH") appears to offer a choice of which strategy to use: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/HH/html/vif.html

If you wanted to write your own, then you already have the code in the form of the `corvif` and `myvif` functions on the page you linked to. The `corvif` function uses the `myvif` function, which is model-based. So you could insert code to check for the presence of the first argument's class in the vector of methods returned by `methods(vcov)`.